# Raspberry pi 2 os.System() command returning 0

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, os.system

OK so I am using a raspberry pi 2 and using python to run a command on terminal. Usually I'm using os.system('*terminal Command here*'). the problem with that is, when i run the program using *sudo python3 filename* it will print the command i want it to but it also prints a *0*. I'm guessing that the 0 is a sign that the command ran successfully but i don't want the 0 to appear. Is there any way to get rid of it returning 0

Comment: I recommend use [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) in >= v3.5

Comment: Python doesn't print anything unless you ask it to. Can you show us your code?

Answer (score -3):

My Code is:

```
import os
import sys

print(os.system("sudo arp -a"))
```

it prints the output for the "Sudo arp -a" command but then after that it also puts a 0 on the next line.

Comment: This is not an answer to your Q. Please update your Q with the problem code and delete this. (It is OK for posters of questions to post an answer, but this.... is not an answer ;-) OK? ) While very general in their definitions and terminology, you need to read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.
Good luck.